# How to apply for TailwindCss active style in nuxt.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, tailwind-css, postcss

Recently I have tried to use tailwindCss from Vuetify.js as Nuxt.js UI framework.
I really made a simple sample like button but it was not work I was expected.
I wanted to add 'active' utility but it wasn't work.

I followed [that.](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/hover-focus-and-other-states)
So first of all, I add tailwind.config.js like that.

tailwind.config.js

```js
module.exports = {
 variants: {
    extend: {
      backgroundColor: ['active'],
    },
  },
}
```

and I made my small button sample like below.

```html
<button
      class="
        active:bg-green-700
        bg-green-500
        rounded
        font-bold
        py-3
        px-5
        text-white
      "
    >
      ButtonTest
    </button>
```

I ran these code, button never active.
Are there other settings necessary to use?
Does anyone advise me, please?

Comment: As shown here, there is no additional configuration required: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/hover-focus-and-other-states#active But you maybe forgot something else aka the issue is not coming from those 2 files. You're using Tailwind2 here? Also, do you have the green color on the background at least? Did you checked for the `active` state via a simulation thanks to your browser devtools?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? What is the "active" state you're looking for? Here's a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/cocky-wilbur-gofg9?file=/components/TButton.vue) example of Nuxt with Tailwind using your code.
When the button is not clicked on (it's not active) it's green. When you press mousedown, the background turns blue (meaning the button is active).

Comment: Yeah, maybe try `hover` to debug it more easily.